# Ideal Folder Structure in MVC 3 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, structure

I am Just started a new MVC3 application.I am using EF fro data base access .I have doubts about folder structure .

Here i am attaching solution explorer picture my application

[image]

I Created 3 folders in Models Folder

1.View Models  - this contains view modes which will use to display informations

2.Domain Model - I am using entity framework .So i put all edmx files and related files .

3 . Businness Logic - Here i write all service function .Say if i want to add new ad, i will create an object of adsServices class and call a function in that class from controller . Thiese functions will use Entity frame work to access database .

**Question**

1.Is my folder structure is ideal folder structure? if not, please tell your suggestion.

2.Is it a good idea Creating  entity data model for each module in the application ? (eg:ads,categories)

**Note :** My application is an average sized appilcation .just not too big.

Answer (score 4):

> 1.Is my folder structure is ideal folder structure?

There is no ideal structure. Structure depends on the type of the application, size, development methodology. It is better to create another project to hold the domain entities and services.

> 2.Is it a good idea Creating entity data model for each module in the application ? (eg:ads,categories)

This also depends on the size of the application and the boundaries in your business logic(eg: One context for Sales logic and another for Security). In your case a single context is enough.